# keep the icon original size on android action bar

Tags: android, html, android-actionbar

```
<style name="ActionBarStyle"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/pink</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/header</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:height">79px</item>
</style>
```

Above is my action bar style. the icon's original size is 41px in height. What i want is to keep the original size and center it vertically in the cation bar. But right now, the icon is stretch to fill the 79 px in height. Is it by default to stretch the icon to fill the space or what ?
Please point me to the right direction to solve this, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an `<item>` like this to your action bar:

   ```
   <item
       android:title="my_icon"
       app:actionLayout="@layout/my_icon_layout"
       app:showAsAction="always"
       />
   ```

Notice the *my_icon_layout* line.

2. Create a *my_icon_layout.xml* in your res/layout folder that looks something like this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="41px">   
   <ImageView
       android:src="@drawable/header"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:scaleType="centerInside"
       />
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

Should work for you.